# Crystal Report Reading Order in Formula WorkShop

Tags: crystal-reports

[image]

This my condition in Crystal Report workshop formula with Crystal Syntax. I can't find any blog about Reading order *Left to Right* Text condition.

Currently the field EHEAD is *right to left* format and I want to format that field to *left to right* if the condition is true. 
Can someone help me? Please! Onegai!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TRY ALIGNMENT OF TEXT IN CRYSTAL REPORT**

```
IF {DETAIL.EHEAD} = TRIM("OK") THEN  crRightAligned
ELSE crLeftAligned

// crDefaultHorAligned
// crLeftAligned
// crCenteredHorizontally
// crRightAligned
// crJustified
```